# Node.js JSON Encode – Array Output Is Empty

Tags: json, node.js

I wroted this code to get a value from a database column to output with in JSON array. I succeeded to get it on the browser console, so I tried it with another value and used the same format to the code to passing it from my class file to the router app.post on the other file. I can see it on the terminal when I use `console.log`, but I can't see the output in the browser response, so what's wrong?

The code that successfully prints output:

`auth.js`, router part

```
app.post('/dispalymove', function (req, res, next) {

var lMove="";


if(req.body.MoveString !== null){
     Move.setMoveUserId(req.user.id);
     Move.setMoveString(req.body.MoveString);
     lMove = a.getLastMove(req.user.GameId,function(move){
      console.log("Return from display move:",move);

      });


    }
     var output = {"msg":lMove, "loggedin":"true"};

     res.send(JSON.stringify(output));



});
```

The function that I call on `move.js` file:

```
getLastMove(id,callback){


    var MoveRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";

    var query = connection.query(MoveRequest, function(err,rows, result) {

    if (rows.length == 0) { 
        return callback ("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
    }
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i in rows) {

        var move = rows[i].MoveString; 
            if (rows[i].GameId == id){

                callback(move);
            }

        }
    }


    });


        var move="rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
        return move;


}
```

The response on the browser console when the output is successful:

```
msg:"rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1" 
loggedin:"true"
```

the outputting code that have the problem

```
app.post('/getcolor', function (req, res, next) {

var lCol="";

if(req.body.MoveString !== null){
     Move.setMoveUserId(req.user.id);
     lCol = a.getColor(req.user.id,function(col){
     console.log("Return from getcolor:",col)
             //the the value that i get on terminal "Return from getcolor:white"

     });
    }

     var output = {"msg":lCol, "loggedin":"true"};
     res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
});
```

The function that I call from the other file:

```
getColor(id,callback){

    var ColRequest = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id";

    var query = connection.query(ColRequest, function(err,rows, result) {

    if (rows.length == 0) { 
        return callback ("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");
    }
    if (rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i in rows) {

            var col = rows[i].GameColor;

            if (rows[i].id == id){

                 callback(col);
                }

        }
    }
    });

        var col="";
        return callback(col);
}
```

The value that I get on my browser console response output just

```
loggedin:"true"
```

that should be like that

```
msg:"white"
loggedin:"true"
```

I tried to write this code with php 
to post getcolor like that

```
session_start();
include "../classes/move.php";
$lCol="";
if(isset($_POST['MoveString'])){
    $move = new move();
    $move->setMoveUserId($_SESSION['UserId']);
    $lCol=$move->getColor($_SESSION['UserId']);
}  
$output = array("msg"=>"$lCol", "loggedin"=>"true");
echo json_encode($output);
```

and the function that i call

```
public function getColor($id){
    include "../../connectToDB.php";

    $ColRequest=$_db->query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY UserId");
    $existCount = $ColRequest->rowCount();

    if ($existCount == 0) { // evaluate the count
        return "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1";
    }
    if ($existCount > 0) {
        while($row = $ColRequest->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $userID = $row["UserId"];               
            $col = $row["GameColor"];                   
            if($userID == $id) {
                return $col;

            }
        }
    }
    $col="";
    return $col;
}
```

and the output was that on browser console responses

```
msg:"white"
loggedin:"true"
```

Comment: Ignoring errors returned via asynchronous callbacks is _never_ a good idea.

Comment: @partycoder thanks but that did't make any different still output empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of `lCol = a.getColor(req.user.id,function(col)`:
`lCol` is undefined here because `getColor` returns nothing, it expects a callback and gives you a value in this callback (while `getLastMove` in the contrary does return something). Try with :

```
app.post('/getcolor', function (req, res, next) {

    var lCol = "";

    if (req.body.MoveString !== null) {
        Move.setMoveUserId(req.user.id);
        // lCol = <=== useless because a.getcolor returns nothing
        a.getColor(req.user.id, function (col) {
            console.log("Return from getcolor:", col)
            //the the value that i get on terminal "Return from getcolor:white"
            res.json({"msg": col, "loggedin": "true"}); // <=== here you have a defined lCol
        });
    } else {
        var output = {"msg": lCol, "loggedin": "true"}; // <=== here lCol always equals ""
        res.json(output);
    }

    // var output = {"msg": lCol, "loggedin": "true"}; // <=== here lCol always equals undefined (when req.body.MoveString !== null)
    // res.send(JSON.stringify(output));

});
```

**Edit**: in the `getColor` and `getLastMove` function you sould **not** return anthing: just use the callback: because `connection.query` is asynchronous any return will be invalid; In `getColor` your are doing 
        `var col="";
        return callback(col);` so you will always have a "" response.
 Beware: do not call a callback function several times when it ends to a server response (you can't send multiple responses for one request): your callback calls are in a loop, **they should not**, just **call it once**.